# SOLR 9 http response time is very slow while query itself is fast

Tags: solr

While trying to setup SOLR 9 in docker, I noticed its taking too long to send any request back, even Admin UI is loading extremely slowly, however the `QTime` in response is not much so solr internal queries is faster, as you can see from screenshot below `QTime` is just **18ms** however request took **~25s** to finish.
I tried searching for this issue but couldn’t find anything related to this.

[image]

> Similarly its taking too long to load static files for Admin panel.

[image]

> PS: Internet speed/connectivity at the client is not an issue here.

Comment: Since they're all multiplies of 4, I'm guessing there's some sort of timeout happening - something like broken DNS lookups for reverse lookups, ipv6 vs ipv4 timeouts, etc. Try accessing the server through 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost or similiar.

Comment: @MatsLindh Solr itself is running behind a proxy, it runs smoothly in local with internet access, I am guessing it talks to some server before responding.